# Add multisite search capability?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

A lot of graphics questions are asked on SO or gamedev (and possibly others?). It'd be very useful IMO if our site search tool could search some of these other sites as well. You can of course search on the main stackexchange site to search all sites, or use filters to build a multisite search (but then you have to edit the filter to change search terms). But I wonder if it would be relatively easy to add results from a handful of these other sites so computergraphics can be more of a hub for all of this content.

Do we want something like this? Maybe it could be a link or extra field when the search help pops up?

Comment: Would certainly be very helpful. I guess it should be implemented in a way, that each community can select which additional sites should be searched and which tags are considered. Otherwise, I end up getting answers from totally unrelated sites by just using the wrong search terms.